# Package Dependecies Cannot Be Resolved : during installation of updated software

Tags: grub2, package-management, dependencies

I have just started Software Updater and got notification while installing updated software :

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolvedI 
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
grub-efi-amd64-signed: Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.02+dfsg1-5) but 2.04-1ubuntu26.15 is to be installed
```

Please advise how I can resolve that problem.

Comment: Software Updater's output is sometimes insufficient for troubleshooting. Open a terminal. Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` copy the complete output of both, and paste both into your question above.

Comment: After running sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade the problem is resolved. Thanks a lot for advice.